# How can admin create a node on behalf of another user?

Tags: 7, users

Is there any module that allow the administrator user to create content on behalf of another user? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create/edit nodes, under *Authoring information*, in the field *Authored by*, you can type any username that exists in your system.

Comment: To future readers: This is true when the user account you are using has the right permission; the first user created when installing Drupal has it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Masquerade](https://drupal.org/project/masquerade) module for this purpose. Give the proper permission to the user-type(such as administrator) to use it.

User-type with permission can masquerade as other username and do everything on that user's behalf, including adding node as well.

Comment: Using cannon to kill a housefly ;) Look at answer by sly. Sometimes experienced pals tends to forget sweet simplicity of tools obvious to new ones, I guess. Happens to me, too.

Comment: @Mołot - Canon to kill a housefly :) ha ha